# Cassandra how to model table with an ordered column that will change?

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to model a table of content which has a timestamp, ordered by the timestamp. However I want that timestamp to change if a user decides to edit the content, (so that the content reappears at the top of the list).

I know that you can't change a primary key column so I'm at a loss of how something like this would be structured. Below is a sample table.

```
CREATE TABLE content(
id uuid
category text
last_update_time timestamp
PRIMARY KEY((category, id),last_update_time)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (last_update_time);
```

How should I model this table if I want the data to be ordered by a column that can change?

Comment: You can't update the timestamp in case it's a part of the primary key. Do you really need to order by timestamp in Cassandra instead of just do the ordering in the client?

Answer (score -1):

2 solutions

1) If you don't care having update history

```
CREATE TABLE content(
id uuid
category text
last_update_time timestamp
PRIMARY KEY((category, id))

// Retrieve last update
SELECT * FROM content WHERE category = 'xxx' AND id = yyy;
```

2) If you want to keep an history of updates

```
CREATE TABLE content(
id uuid
category text
last_update_time timestamp
PRIMARY KEY((category, id),last_update_time)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (last_update_time DESC);

// Retrieve last update
SELECT * FROM content WHERE category = 'xxx' AND id = yyy LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: How are these solutions? The first one isn't ordered and the second one doesn't allow me to update the timestamp

Comment: For the second one, you just insert a new value when the update occurs: `INSERT INTO content(id, category,  last_update_time ) VALUES(...)` then to get the **latest** update from Cassandra : `SELECT * FROM content WHERE category = 'xxx' AND id = yyy LIMIT 1;`. Please note that all the update history is kept. To clean up the update history you need to do it manually by the application